# R recoding using .default got length error

Tags: r, recode

My database looks like below.
[image]

I try the following code, in order to recode "EDUC" column.

```
gun.control$EDUC <- recode(gun.control$EDUC,
                       'IAP' = NULL,
                       'DK' = NULL,
                       .default = gun.control$EDUC,
                       .missing = NULL)
```

However, there shows an error saying `"Error: '.default' must be length 24 or one, not 62466."`.
I've try `length(gun.control$EDUC)` and it is 62366 long. The result of `unique(gun.control$EDUC)` shows `Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 IAP DK NA`

I dont know in which part I did it wrong and resulting in this problem. Anyone can possible see any solution here? Really appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have `NA` values in the data hence `recode` returns an error. Also instead of `NULL` you should replace the data with `NA`. :

```
gun.control$EDUC[gun.control$EDUC %in% c('IAP', 'DK')] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems works for me. However, I check and there is no `NA` values in it.

Comment: That is strange. Can you provide a reproducible example for us to test?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
gun.control %>%
        mutate(EDUC = replace(EDUC, EDUC %in% c("IAP", "DK"), NA_character_))
```